# Spark dataframes convert nested JSON to seperate columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a stream of JSONs with following structure that gets converted to dataframe

```
{
  "a": 3936,
  "b": 123,
  "c": "34",
  "attributes": {
    "d": "146",
    "e": "12",
    "f": "23"
  }
}
```

The dataframe show functions results in following output

```
sqlContext.read.json(jsonRDD).show

+----+-----------+---+---+
|   a| attributes|  b|  c|
+----+-----------+---+---+
|3936|[146,12,23]|123| 34|
+----+-----------+---+---+
```

How can I split attributes column (nested JSON structure) into **attributes.d, attributes.e and attributes.f** as *seperate* columns into a new dataframe, so I can have columns as a, b, c, attributes.d, attributes.e and attributes.f in the new dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want columns named from `a` to `f`:

  ```
  df.select("a", "b", "c", "attributes.d", "attributes.e", "attributes.f")
  ```
- If you want columns named with `attributes.` prefix:

  ```
  df.select($"a", $"b", $"c", $"attributes.d" as "attributes.d", $"attributes.e" as "attributes.e", $"attributes.f" as "attributes.f")
  ```
- If names of your columns are supplied from an external source (e.g. configuration):

  ```
  val colNames: Seq("a", "b", "c", "attributes.d", "attributes.e", "attributes.f")

  df.select(colNames.head, colNames.tail: _*).toDF(colNames:_*)
  ```

Comment: This would work per my question. Thanks! One of the thing I missed to mention in the question is to have the generic approach where the column names can be different for different messages in a dataframe, thus column names  to be processed are configured externally. In other words, is it possible to avoid hard-coding column names in the select function. Unfortunately, select(tags.head, tags.tail: _*) does not work.

Comment: OK, I was able to get this: val tags: Seq("a", "b", "c", "attributes.d", "attributes.e", "attributes.f");df.select(tags.head, tags.tail: _*).toDF(tags:_*).show(). If it makes sense, I can edit your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the attributes.d notation, you can create new columns and you will have them in your DataFrame. Look at the withColumn() method in Java.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Python**

1. Extract the DataFrame by using the pandas Lib of python.
2. Change the data type from 'str' to 'dict'.
3. Get the values of each features.
4. Save the results to a new file.

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")  # load the csv file from your disk
   json_data = data['Desc']        # get the DataFrame of Desc
   data = data.drop('Desc', 1)     # delete Desc column
   Total, Defective = [], []       # setout list

   for i in json_data:
       i = eval(i)     # change the data type from 'str' to 'dict'
       Total.append(i['Total'])    # append 'Total' feature
       Defective.append(i['Defective'])    # append 'Defective' feature

   # finally,complete the DataFrame
   data['Total'] = Total
   data['Defective'] = Defective

   data.to_csv("result.csv")       # save to the result.csv and check it
   ```